# RedCloth loaderror on ruby 2.0.0 [i386-mingw32]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, redcloth

When I upgraded my rails 3.2.13 application (on Win XP) from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.0.0, it crashed due to gem RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32).

Message: `couldn't load 2.0/redcloth_scan (LoadError)`. In other words: `/lib/2.0/redcloth_scan.so` does not exist in the gem.

Is there any solution to this problem?

(Unfortunately, RedCloth is the *only* Ruby tool that handles Textile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to stay with 1.9.3 for now, if you must use RedCloth.

[RedCloth doesn't seem to support 2.0.0 yet.](http://jgarber.lighthouseapp.com/projects/13054/tickets/259-RedCloth-on-ruby-200p0-2013-02-24-i386-mingw32-not-working#ticket-259-1)

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

1. Install RedCloth-4.2.9:

   gem install RedCloth --platform==ruby -V
2. Create this directory:

   ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\RedCloth-4.2.9\ext\2.0
3. Copy all files to that directory from:

   ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\RedCloth-4.2.9\ext\redcloth_scan

Then you can use RedCloth in Ruby 2.0.  I tried with jekyll 1.12.1, and that works.